Update JSON column value By using condition
I am trying to update a JSON value stored in an MS SQL table, so here is the situation. We have a table named SupportPlans with a column named PlanValue. We need to update the MedicationTasks based on the following criteria: Find the task that has the following values:
SupportType.Value = Assist
Route.Type.Value = Oral
PlanValue is not null
Then update Route.Type.Value to Administer in the array.
"CareService": {
    "CarePackages": [
        {
            "CarePackageId": "28606061-1130-4274-9c18-08dc346ee5d9",
            "Title": "Morning visit",
            "CareTasks": [
                {
                    "Criticality": null,
                    "Description": null,
                    "TaskAddonId": "50bdc87c-e50a-4b94-a4a7-adffe22704c6",
                    "TaskId": "bef32649-a0d2-423f-85c6-2620f2a6ead0",
                    "Title": "Leisure centre",
                    "Outcomes": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Community & recreation",
                            "Note": "Making use of necessary facilities/services in the community including transport and recreational facilities"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Mental Health",
                            "Note": "Managing and maintaining my communication, mental health and emotional wellbeing"
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Social and economic",
                            "Note": "Managing and maintaining my social and economic wellbeing"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Period": {
                        "End": null,
                        "Start": "2024-02-23T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    "TimePeriod": {
                        "End": "11:00:00.0000000",
                        "Start": "10:00:00.0000000"
                    },
                    "Type": {
                        "Value": "Care"
                    },
                    "WeeklyRepetition": {
                        "Every": 1,
                        "Repeat": {
                            "Weekdays": [
                                {
                                    "Value": "Monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Wednesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Thursday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Friday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Saturday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Sunday"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "MedicationTasks": [
                {
                    "AdditionalInstructions": null,
                    "MedicationId": "494f5577-5546-40fc-8d6c-54b2d2067bc1",
                    "MedicationTaskId": "c065d607-6258-45eb-a75d-08dc34726ba2",
                    "Name": "Ibuprofen 400",
                    "Dose": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Quantity": 2,
                        "Range": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Quantity"
                        }
                    },
                    "Period": {
                        "End": null,
                        "Start": "2024-02-23T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    "Route": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Oral"
                        }
                    },
                    "SupportType": {
                        "Value": "Assist"
                    },
                    "WeeklyRepetition": {
                        "Every": 1,
                        "Repeat": {
                            "Weekdays": [
                                {
                                    "Value": "Monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Wednesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Thursday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Friday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Saturday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Sunday"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "AdditionalInstructions": null,
                    "MedicationId": "3d126b9c-bc77-4d22-9bd5-c0865b100310",
                    "MedicationTaskId": "947fa146-2747-4c00-d853-08dc5a19909b",
                    "Name": "Paracetamol",
                    "Dose": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Quantity": 100,
                        "Range": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Quantity"
                        }
                    },
                    "Period": {
                        "End": null,
                        "Start": "2024-04-12T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    "Route": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Oral"
                        }
                    },
                    "SupportType": {
                        "Value": "Assist"
                    },
                    "WeeklyRepetition": {
                        "Every": 1,
                        "Repeat": {
                            "Weekdays": [
                                {
                                    "Value": "Monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Wednesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Thursday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Friday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Saturday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Sunday"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Occurance": {
                "EndAfter": null,
                "FromMinutes": 600,
                "ToMinutes": 660,
                "CriticalDays": {
                    "Weekdays": []
                },
                "End": null,
                "Start": {
                    "Value": "2024-02-23T00:00:00+00:00"
                },
                "WeeklyRepetitionRules": {
                    "Every": 1,
                    "Repeat": {
                        "Weekdays": [
                            {
                                "Value": "Monday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Tuesday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Wednesday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Thursday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Friday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Saturday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Sunday"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "CarePackageId": "6f50ff9a-914d-4345-9c1d-08dc346ee5d9",
            "Title": "Sitting visit",
            "CareTasks": [],
            "MedicationTasks": [],
            "Occurance": {
                "EndAfter": null,
                "FromMinutes": 900,
                "ToMinutes": 960,
                "CriticalDays": {
                    "Weekdays": []
                },
                "End": null,
                "Start": {
                    "Value": "2024-02-23T00:00:00+00:00"
                },
                "WeeklyRepetitionRules": {
                    "Every": 1,
                    "Repeat": {
                        "Weekdays": [
                            {
                                "Value": "Monday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Tuesday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Wednesday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Thursday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Friday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Saturday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Sunday"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "CarePackageId": "dbc58fa5-248c-4780-c5e6-08dc384ef300",
            "Title": "Shopping visit",
            "CareTasks": [
                {
                    "Criticality": null,
                    "Description": null,
                    "TaskAddonId": "14c6aec3-72ab-4bf7-8fd3-8f239f19e0a7",
                    "TaskId": "7081cc16-1250-44bd-90c3-01b223d8c7b4",
                    "Title": "Test Task For Dana",
                    "Outcomes": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Caring responsibilities",
                            "Note": "Caring out any caring responsibilities"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Period": {
                        "End": null,
                        "Start": "2024-04-11T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    "TimePeriod": {
                        "End": "14:00:00.0000000",
                        "Start": "13:00:00.0000000"
                    },
                    "Type": {
                        "Value": "Care"
                    },
                    "WeeklyRepetition": {
                        "Every": 1,
                        "Repeat": {
                            "Weekdays": [
                                {
                                    "Value": "Monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Wednesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Thursday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Friday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Saturday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Sunday"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "MedicationTasks": [
                {
                    "AdditionalInstructions": null,
                    "MedicationId": "035691f0-512d-4b38-8410-23c6a1abb359",
                    "MedicationTaskId": "ff194bb1-dc99-4136-d852-08dc5a19909b",
                    "Name": "Paracetamol",
                    "Dose": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Quantity": 200,
                        "Range": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Quantity"
                        }
                    },
                    "Period": {
                        "End": null,
                        "Start": "2024-04-11T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    "Route": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Oral"
                        }
                    },
                    "SupportType": {
                        "Value": "Assist"
                    },
                    "WeeklyRepetition": {
                        "Every": 1,
                        "Repeat": {
                            "Weekdays": [
                                {
                                    "Value": "Monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Wednesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Thursday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Friday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Saturday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Sunday"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Occurance": {
                "EndAfter": null,
                "FromMinutes": 780,
                "ToMinutes": 840,
                "CriticalDays": {
                    "Weekdays": []
                },
                "End": null,
                "Start": {
                    "Value": "2024-02-28T00:00:00+00:00"
                },
                "WeeklyRepetitionRules": {
                    "Every": 1,
                    "Repeat": {
                        "Weekdays": [
                            {
                                "Value": "Monday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Tuesday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Wednesday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Thursday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Friday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Saturday"
                            },
                            {
                                "Value": "Sunday"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

I have tried following SQL query and it work but it add mr in josn
UPDATE SupportPlans
SET PlanValue = (
    SELECT JSON_MODIFY(cp.value, '$.MedicationTasks', (
            SELECT JSON_MODIFY(mt.value, '$.SupportType.Value', 'Administer') AS mt
            FROM OPENJSON(cp.value, '$.MedicationTasks') AS mt
            WHERE JSON_VALUE(mt.value, '$.SupportType.Value') = 'Assist'
              AND JSON_VALUE(mt.value, '$.Route.Type.Value') = 'Oral'
            FOR JSON PATH
        )) AS CarePackages
    FROM OPENJSON(PlanValue, '$.CareService.CarePackages') AS cp
    FOR JSON PATH
)
WHERE PlanValue IS NOT NULL
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(PlanValue, '$.CareService.CarePackages') AS cp
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(cp.value, '$.MedicationTasks') AS mt
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(mt.value, '$.SupportType.Value') = 'Assist'
    AND JSON_VALUE(mt.value, '$.Route.Type.Value') = 'Oral'
)

so after update it become
"MedicationTasks": [
            {
                "mt": {
                    "AdditionalInstructions": null,
                    "MedicationId": "494f5577-5546-40fc-8d6c-54b2d2067bc1",
                    "MedicationTaskId": "c065d607-6258-45eb-a75d-08dc34726ba2",
                    "Name": "Ibuprofen 400",
                    "Dose": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Quantity": 2,
                        "Range": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Quantity"
                        }
                    },
                    "Period": {
                        "End": null,
                        "Start": "2024-02-23T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    "Route": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Oral"
                        }
                    },
                    "SupportType": {
                        "Value": "Administer"
                    },
                    "WeeklyRepetition": {
                        "Every": 1,
                        "Repeat": {
                            "Weekdays": [
                                {
                                    "Value": "Monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Wednesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Thursday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Friday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Saturday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Sunday"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "mt": {
                    "AdditionalInstructions": null,
                    "MedicationId": "3d126b9c-bc77-4d22-9bd5-c0865b100310",
                    "MedicationTaskId": "947fa146-2747-4c00-d853-08dc5a19909b",
                    "Name": "Paracetamol",
                    "Dose": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Quantity": 100,
                        "Range": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Quantity"
                        }
                    },
                    "Period": {
                        "End": null,
                        "Start": "2024-04-12T00:00:00+00:00"
                    },
                    "Route": {
                        "Other": null,
                        "Type": {
                            "Value": "Oral"
                        }
                    },
                    "SupportType": {
                        "Value": "Administer"
                    },
                    "WeeklyRepetition": {
                        "Every": 1,
                        "Repeat": {
                            "Weekdays": [
                                {
                                    "Value": "Monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Wednesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Thursday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Friday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Saturday"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Value": "Sunday"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]

It should not add "mt":
Any one has any idea?

If you need to update specific parts of the document I wouldn't store it as JSON. Just store it in relational tables. SQL Server isn't a document database. Replacing the whole of a large string when you want to update a specific value in it won't be efficient

This is something that is already in use by the system. I can't move it to a relational table at this stage.

Finally I am able to generate the query, may be someone can share better solution.
DECLARE @Id uniqueidentifier, @CarePackageIndex int, @MedicationTasksIndex 
int; 
DECLARE updateCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
SupportPlans.Id,
CONVERT(int, CarePackageJson.[key]) AS CarePackageIndex, 
CONVERT(int, MedicationTaskJson.[key]) AS MedicationTasksIndex 
FROM SupportPlans
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(SupportPlans.PlanValue, '$.CareService.CarePackages') 
CarePackageJson
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CarePackageJson.[value], '$.MedicationTasks') 
MedicationTaskJson
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(MedicationTaskJson.[value], '$') WITH (
SupportType NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.SupportType.Value',
RouteTypeValue NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Route.Type.Value',
RouteTypeOther NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Route.Other',
MedicationTaskId NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.MedicationTaskId'
) Task
WHERE Task.SupportType = 'Assist'
AND Task.RouteTypeValue = 'Oral'  
AND Task.RouteTypeOther IS NULL;

OPEN updateCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM updateCursor INTO @Id, @CarePackageIndex, 
@MedicationTasksIndex;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
UPDATE SupportPlans
SET PlanValue = JSON_MODIFY(
                        PlanValue,
                        CONCAT('$.CareService.CarePackages[', 
@CarePackageIndex, '].MedicationTasks[', @MedicationTasksIndex, 
'].SupportType.Value'),
                        'Administer'
                    )
WHERE Id = @Id;

FETCH NEXT FROM updateCursor INTO @Id, @CarePackageIndex, 
@MedicationTasksIndex;
END;

CLOSE updateCursor;
DEALLOCATE updateCursor;

